Confusion about the maximum number of Java threads under Debian12
foreword
I want to find out the maximum number of threads supported by the jvm under the default configuration, and figure out what configuration changes can increase this number.

environment

VirtualBox 7 + debian-12.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
Java 21 + SpringBoot3

koril@TestDebian:~/project$ uname -a
Linux TestDebian 6.1.0-27-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.115-1 (2024-11-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
koril@TestDebian:~/project$ java -version
java version "21.0.5" 2024-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.5+9-LTS-239)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.5+9-LTS-239, mixed mode, sharing)

my code
controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/thread")
public class ThreadController {

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String add(int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            new Thread(new TestTask()).start();
        }
        return "Add " + num + " threads success";
    }
}

TestTask.java:
public class TestTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

my test
I use jconsole to see the number of jvm threads and Linux top command to see the memory usage.
This is start jar script:
#!/bin/bash
java \
 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.202 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
 -jar study-java-thread.jar

I logged the number of threads in jconsole when it gave the following error:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
test results

1CPU 1GB
threads: 2400, memory usage: 51.8%

1CPU 2GB
threads: 5057, memory usage: 31.2%

1CPU 4GB
threads: 9985, memory usage: 22.7%

1CPU 8GB
threads: 9985, memory usage: 12%

1CPU 16GB
threads: 9985, memory usage: 6.3%


confusion
Why does the number always stay at 9985 as the memory of the virtual machine increases?
I modified the following options, but it seems to have no real effect:

Xms, Xmx, Xss
ulimit -u 100000
/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

Is there a formula that can calculate the thread limit?

IDK the reason for the hard limit. Once upon a million-billion years ago, it would have been the size of the Linux kernel's statically allocated process table, but that was then,... Anyway, if you really need so many threads, have you considered using Java's new virtual threads?
